# Need common date function that support Oracle and DB2

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

am using date function that works fine in DB2. But now when we switch to Oracle, it is failing as there is no date function in Oracle.Now I have to change code to support both databases.

Is there any date function that supports in both database ?

```
coalesce(date(V_ORG_ID_EXPR_DT_FIELD),  '12/31/9999')
```

Comment: DATE is a data type in Oracle. I think you'll find that defining a function (or family of functions) named "DATE" which **returns** a DATE (data type) is going to be very difficult, if not impossible. You're probably better off defining a set of user-defined functions which perform equivalent functionality in both databases, accounting for the differences in how each database represent dates and times.

Comment: `DATE` in DB2 is strictly a calendar date (eg, YYYY-MM-DD).  `DATE` in Oracle is a calendar date plus a time (eg, YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss).  Have you accounted for this in your queries (eg, [only use an exclusive upper-bound](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common))?  Note too that `MM/DD/YYYY` is not a portable format, and you would be better served using the ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD).  Why are you trying to run the exact same statement on both databases?  There are multiple other differences, so this will not be the only issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both databases happen to have a function called `to_date()`.  Both also support the `date` keyword for introducing date constants.  The the following should work in both databases:

```
coalesce(to_date(V_ORG_ID_EXPR_DT_FIELD, '<your date format here>'),  date '9999-12-31')
```

Comment: I got ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR error